# Why are some imported React-Native Redux actions changing values and triggering onEffects multiple times?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, asynchronous, redux

Here is my setup:

`// store/actions/user.js`

```
export const discoverFollowingStatus = followsId => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const userId = getState().user.user.id;
    findFollowingFromTo(userId, followsId).then(following => {
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_FOLLOWING_STATUS,
        payload: {
          followsId,
          following: following !== null,
        },
      });
    });
  };
};
```

`// component.js`

```
import {
  discoverFollowingStatus,
} from '../store/actions/user';
...
useEffect(() => {
    discoverFollowingStatus(followedUserId);
    console.log(discoverFollowingStatus);
  }, [followedUserId, discoverFollowingStatus]);
```

The console is printing lots of functions that aren't grouping together:
[image: logs]

The big problem is that the screen is constantly re-rendering because the useEffect is triggering. Why would that imported constant change and trigger it?

Comment: it seems that `followedUserId` or `discoverFollowingStatus` is updated. So it triggers  `discoverFollowingStatus`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you have two objects/values inside `[]` at the end of your useEffect. This should fix it if you want to keep watching those two values.

```js
import {
  discoverFollowingStatus,
} from '../store/actions/user';
...
useEffect(() => {
    if(followedUserId && discoverFollowingStatus){
    discoverFollowingStatus(followedUserId);
    console.log(discoverFollowingStatus);
    }
  }, [followedUserId, discoverFollowingStatus]);
```

Note here that `discoverFollowingStatus` will only be triggered if both `discoverFollowingStatus` and `followedUserId` are defined this time.

Otherwise it is recommended in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-use-multiple-effects-to-separate-concerns) to split your useEffect for separation of concerns. You should be using a useEffect to set a state when `followedUserId` is defined and safe to use by `discoverFollowingStatus`

Comment: My component continues to keep rendering over and over again. Does it have to do with the fact that that action changes the state?

Comment: If you are listening to a value that gets constantly refreshed in your state, then yes. You can perhaps look into useMemo in that case.